# cron jobsare not working on ubuntu ec2 machine. Multiple methods attempted

Tags: cron, amazon-ec2

Test cronjobb:

```
* * * * * /bin/echo Test >> /user/ubuntu/test.txt
```

I tried including this in multiple places with no luck:

1. added in `crontab -e`
2. added in `sudo crontab -e`
3. added in `sudo vim /etc/crontab`

   - This command changes slightly to include the user:
   - `* * * * * root /bin/echo Test >> /user/ubuntu/test.txt`

NOTE: I've tested this command on my local machine and it worked.

I also tried to start/restart my cron. Here is the status:

```
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-01-29 16:50:04 UTC; 35min ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 3996 (cron)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           └─3996 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Jan 29 17:23:01 ip-172-31-36-72 cron[3996]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
Jan 29 17:23:01 ip-172-31-36-72 CRON[5379]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 29 17:23:01 ip-172-31-36-72 CRON[5379]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jan 29 17:24:01 ip-172-31-36-72 cron[3996]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
Jan 29 17:24:01 ip-172-31-36-72 CRON[5392]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 29 17:24:01 ip-172-31-36-72 CRON[5393]: (root) CMD (/bin/echo Test >> /user/ubuntu/test.txt)
Jan 29 17:24:01 ip-172-31-36-72 CRON[5392]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jan 29 17:25:01 ip-172-31-36-72 CRON[5399]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 29 17:25:01 ip-172-31-36-72 CRON[5400]: (root) CMD (/bin/echo Test >> /user/ubuntu/test.txt)
Jan 29 17:25:01 ip-172-31-36-72 CRON[5399]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Edit: Home Directory:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-36-72:~$ pwd
/home/ubuntu
```

Comment: Does your ec2 instance have a `/user/ubuntu` directory? That's not part of the Linux [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)

Comment: yep, I added the pwd result.

Answer (score 0):

As per your `pwd` result, your home directory is `/home/ubuntu`. But you are trying to redirect result to `/user/ubuntu`.

Can you add

```
* * * * * /bin/echo Test >> /home/ubuntu/test.txt
```

to `crontab -e`

Also, give the output of the command `ls /user/ubuntu`